# SP2013 - all Analytics usage report show zero count

Tags: web-analytics, analytics

In our test environment with 2 WFE, 2 APP and 1 SQL. The "popularity trend" and "most popular items" reports are all showing zero.

I have followed this blog to enable Analytics usage definition receiver & Page requests usage definition receiver:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2013/08/26/powershell-script-to-workaround-no-data-in-sharepoint-2013-usage.aspx

After one day still zero for all reports.

Also I run following Powershell to verify whether Analystic data exist:

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$site = Get-SPSite "https://company.com/sites/ABC/"
$result = $searchApp.GetRollupAnalyticsItemData(1,[System.Guid]::Empty,$site.ID,[System.Guid]::Empty)
$result
```

It return nothing for $result. I think it means nothing in AnalyticsItemData. What else I can check? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Put enter and you get something like this and check what is wrong EventType : 1 SiteId : 9156832e-b9eb-4298-8166-7f7b2e121070 ScopeId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 TenantId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ItemId : 9156832e-b9eb-4298-8166-7f7b2e121070 LastProcessingTime : 16.4.2016 23:00:00 CurrentDate : 30.8.2016 0:00:00 TotalHits : 1357770 TotalUniqueUsers : 151819 LastProcessingHits : 222 LastProcessingUniqueUsers : 78

Comment: sorry? Did you missed the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage reports show up on day 3. Hence I need to wait 2 days after setup the Analytics usage definition receiver & Page requests usage definition receiver.

I guess it is because:

1. I am at timezone GMT+8 but the log are in GMT0
2. The reports will only show up the counts/figures after a single full day's log is accumulated.

Hence I need to wait 2 days. This process cannot be triggered earlier by manually run the related timer jobs. You can only wait. (Maybe change server clock will work but I not dare try)